# Probability of getting k different coupons in a set of S coupons, from an infinite set of N different types of coupons.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, coupon-collector

This is my slight modification to a question in the book "Introduction to Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists" by Sheldon M Ross.

```
Suppose there are N different types of coupons and suppose that each time
one obtains a coupon it is equally likely to be any one of the types. 
Compute the probability that you get exactly k different types of coupons in a set of S coupons.
N>0, k<=S<N.
```

I tried to create the probability mass function but I am not able to come up with the correct one.

Here is mine.

```
Choosing k coupons from N coupons can be done in
Combination(N,k) ways.  -- (1)
```

---

```
k places (1 for each coupon) in a set of S can be chosen in Combination(S,k) ways  -- (2)
```

this is to satisfy the atleast one coupon of each type criteria.

```
These k coupons can arrange themselves in k! ways.  --(3)
```

The remaining (S-k) places can be filled by any of the k coupons. Coupons are replaced as per the question.

```
So it becomes k^(S-k)     --(4)
```

---

Finally the probability to choose one coupon is 1/N (equal for all types) and `thus for a set of S coupons it becomes (1/N)^S    --(5)`

So my answer for the question becomes (1) * (2) * (3) * (4) * (5)
But my answer probability mass function does not sum up to 1. And so I am doing a blunder somewhere. Am I thinking completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be consistent with standard notation, instead of picking $S$ coupons, we will pick $n$.

The number of ways to divide a set of $n$ elements into $k$ **non-empty** subsets is $S(n,k)$, where $S(n,k)$ is the [Stirling Number of the Second Kind.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Thus the number of "favourables" is $\binom{N}{k}k!S(n,k)$, and the required probability is $\frac{\binom{N}{k}k!S(n,k)}{N^n}$.

**Remark:** An Inclusion/Exclusion argument shows that
$$k!S(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i} \binom{k}{i}i^n.$$
The first term $k^n$ counts the number of words of length $n$ that one can make from an alphabet of size $k$. The remaining terms are to make sure that we are only counting the words that have at least one of each of the $k$ letters.

There are a number of useful *recurrences* for the Stirling numbers of the second kind, but no closed form in terms, for example, of factorials.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why did you multiply k! In the numerator?

Comment: Why on earth would you use $S(n,k)$ to calculate the number of ways to chose $k$ objects out of $n$? I think it is a completely different kind of task: no one asks to pigeonhole $n$ objects in $k$ slots: you simply need to choose $k$ objects, and throw away $n-k$. Or I did not understand the problem at all.

Comment: @Shady_arc:  You understood just fine, but the count of the favourables is more complicated than in your answer. The problem is that $k^S$ counts the functions from a set of $S$ elements to a set of $k$ elements. But since we want *exactly* $k$ different types, we want the functions that are **onto**. Your $k^S$, as a very extreme case, counts among others the constant functions, which are not allowed if $k\gt 1$. To put it another way, we want the number of words of length $S$ over an alphabet of $k$ letters, such that **every** letters occur in the word. The $k^S$ counts all words.

Comment: But if we have NcK ways to select set of k types and S(n,k) ways to divide n elements in one such set of k types then why is that k! there? What is that something which is again having k! Ways? Your answer has been very clear and it is the only part I am unable to understand.

Comment: @André Nicolas Thanks! Got it.

Comment: The "extra" $k!$, which cancels the $k!$ in the denominator of $\binom{N}{k}$, is due to the fact I wanted to use the notation $S(n,k)$. I could have used $\binom{N}{k}\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i} \binom{k}{i}i^n$, but wanted to bring in the known and important $S(n,k)$, which is $\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i} \binom{k}{i}i^n$. Bringing in $S(n,k)$ lets us use other known recurrences for $S(n,k)$, or approximations, to do the computation.

Comment: Oops. I am still unable to grasp it. So you have NcK ways to select k sets. We don't care about the order and so this part of the result is over. Let's keep it aside now. We have S(n,k) which has a k! in denominator. Whatever the formula is, it gives us say T number of ways to divide n elements into k types. So wouldn't it be ok to just multiply this T and NcK? Why cancel out k!? I am so sorry, I am unable to understand this easy thing. But unless I know, I won't be able to justify myself that I understand the answer fully.

Comment: The $S(n,k)$ counts the number of ways to divide $n$ objects into $k$ *unordered* types, with at least one object of each type.  It is a peculiarity of the definition of $S(n,k)$.

Comment: Thank you. I had not expected the question to be this tricky. I am glad i asked it here. Otherwise I wouldn't have got to know about Stirling numbers of second kind.

Comment: You are welcome. Perhaps the original question you modified was simpler. In combinatorics, a question can turn from straightforward to complicated by a "minor" wording change.